# Turning folder of word documents (Google Docs) into python usable list of sentences separated by line breaks for reddit bot? (Perl?)

Tags: python, bots, reddit

Turning folder of word documents (Google Docs) into python usable list of sentences separated by line breaks for reddit bot?  (Perl?)

All I know's that I don't know. Hella basic programming question.

This is really a text processing from word document into sentence format. Is there a language like Perl which would make this easier since it's, like scripting right? Just turning the documents into a list and picking out the mistakes?

Simple reddit bot to do basic things. https://www.pythonforengineers.com/build-marvin-the-depressed-reddit-bot-in-python/. Just looking for a way to automate turning the folder of purely text documents (in google docs format, will need to batch export since it's hundreds.)

Some ARG nonesense:

1. spitting out a reply to a mention of a specific phrase in a specific subreddit with a specific single sentence with link. Static, I'd like multi-lined but I'm struggling with the either "\n\n" or a straight up new line in python, but https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1h5u3a/praw_creating_multiline_comments/
2. Respond to username mentions with a random sentence. The thing is, I have a google docs filled with the responses. All usually with line breaks almost invariably. A few probably aren't, but there are a lot of notes and things I want it to spit out. I don't know how to count total sentences in a folder of word documents.

Comment: Please include code examples of what you have tried and explain the specific issues you are encountering.

Comment: @DelenaMalan https://github.com/shantnu/RedditBot/blob/master/Marvin/marvin_bot.py

Comment: @DelenaMalan I have probably thousands of sentences to go in that list that need to be processed from a giant folder of google docs with sentences separated by periods and usually line breaks.